# Should I choose open-jdk or oracle in Linaro 12.08

Tags: arm, java

I am wondering if either of ***open-jdk*** or ***oracle-JDK*** are optimized for  ARM architecture. Or is it ok to simply use one of them.

My platform is Cortex-A9 and my operating system ***Linaro 12.08.***

Comment: The compiled **Java** code is platform independent, although it may have **native** code.  The **native** code will generally call *OS* routines which are optimized.  The other component is the **Java VM** which may implement **JIT** and this can be highly optimized.  *Open-JDK* is open source, so you can compile it specifically for the *Cortex-A9*.  Do you mean optimized custom assembler?  Also the **oracle-JDK** with *JIT* not optimized for the *Cortex-A9* will still be faster than a *non-JIT-VM*.

Comment: Thanks @artlessnoise The reason I am using Linaro rather than the default Ubuntu is because it is optimized for ARM processors.   What I am wondering is that the JIT implementations may differ in the two JDKs. And the JIT that is implemented taking the underlying hardware architecture into account would have more optimizing capabilities which would make it faster.

Comment: Isn't possible to install them both?

Comment: It is possible. I just wanted to choose the better one(if there is such a thing here)

Comment: Choose the open source one.